# Как сгладить этот график используя Java?

Tags: java

```
 import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {


    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("GRAPH");
        //Задаем оси
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        //Имя оси
        yAxis.setLabel("ВІСЬ Y");
        xAxis.setLabel("ВІСЬ Х");
        //Добавляем их на график
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        //Его имя
        lineChart.setTitle("GRAPH");
        //Создаем линию графика
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("ЗАЛЕЖНІСТЬ МЕТАЛІВ ВІД ТЕМПЕРАТУРИ");
        //Втыкаем данные
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 17.5));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));
        //Создаем окно с результатом.
        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь вам поможет

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html

на всякий случай https://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/